# Jquery slider using scrollTo buggy

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am trying to develop a jquery slider using the popular slideTo plugin. I have whipped up a jfiddle so you can see an example of the slider I made, as well as the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mh7Mh/

The result is slightly buggy. It doesn't seem to loop back around when you have reached the last slide, and it should. Take a look at my jquery - I created an if statement that resets the variable which tells scrollTo where to scroll To. The code is pretty self explanatory.

Any help is fixing this would be a huge help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple bugs in the logic of those functions. Here's a revamped version of your JS:

```
// you were defining these vars in every function, not as global vars
var jesse = 0;
var lastSlide = 3;
// your numSlide var was off by one, renamed it to lastSlide

// you were adding these events multiple times for each li
$("#controls a.next").click(function() {
    (jesse==lastSlide)?(jesse=0):(jesse++);
     $("#contentSlider").stop().scrollTo('li:eq(' + jesse + ')', 500);
     return false;
});

$("#controls a.prev").click(function() {
    (jesse==0)?(jesse=lastSlide):(jesse--);
    $("#contentSlider").stop().scrollTo('li:eq(' + jesse + ')', 500);
    return false;
});
```

The usage of `?:` is called a ternary operation. It is similar to an [if/else statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a).

It's general usage is:

```
foo=(booleanExpression)?bar:baz;
// it is equal to
if(booleanExpression){
    foo=bar;
}else{
    foo=baz;
}
```

Comment: I am a bit of a newbie to jQuery so can you comment on this line so I can understand what is going on:  (jesse==lastSlide)?(jesse=0):(jesse++);

Comment: You can use your if/else statement too. I just like using the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(programming)#As_a_ternary_operator) for simple statements.

Answer (score 1):

You have an off by one error.  There are four slides, index 0, 1, 2, 3.

So use this line:

```
if (jesse == numSlides-1) {
```

and these lines:

```
      if (jesse == 0) {
        jesse = numSlides -1;
```

Even though it works this way, it doesn't quite look right.  You'll see what I mean.

Comment: ya that does it. Makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: but your right, it is still buggy, most likely due to @Khez answer...i was adding the events multiple times for each li